# How to put textbox between kendo-grid-column-group and kendo-grid-column?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So i have two columns inside a column group, and i need to put and input between column and column group, i have tried using ng-template before the first grid column tag but didn't works.

[example from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWLln.png)

here's my current code:

```
<kendo-grid-column-group title="column group">
  <!-- TEXTBOX HERE 
    <input kendoTextBox [formControl]="formControlGroup" />
  -->
  <kendo-grid-column title="column A">
    <ng-template kendoGridTemplate let-rowData>
      <div #textboxa>
        <input kendoTextBox [formControl]="formControlA" />
      </div
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column title="column B">
    <ng-template kendoGridTemplate let-rowData>
      <div #textboxb>
        <input kendoTextBox [formControl]="formControlB" />
      </div
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid-column-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `kendoGridHeaderTemplate` directive inside `ng-template` under `kendo-grid-column-group`.

```
<ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
   <input kendoTextBox />
</ng-template>
```

at first i using wrong directive which is `kendoGridTemplate`.